# synchronize svn with subversive

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I downloaded a java project from svn and then I added to Eclipse and now I have installed surversive plugin and I would like to synchronize this project with the from SVN, How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Didn't read the article - [but this might help](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/) - first page of results on Bing (yes really!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project -> Team -> Share Project
then select SVN in the wizard.